# How can I avoid repetitive code for nested sections in XSL Document?

Tags: xml, xslt

I desire to create the same HTML code from XML, even if sections are nested.  Here is an example below, in which I want the exact same HTML to appear whether I'm within "suite/sections/section" or within "suite/sections/section/sections/section".  So the code below displays how I'd like it to, but I'd rather just edit in one spot.

```
<xsl:for-each select="suite/sections/section">
  <div class="section">
    <xsl:for-each select="cases/case">
      My HTML HERE
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div> 
</xsl:for-each>


<xsl:for-each select="suite/sections/section/sections/section">
  <div class="section">
    <xsl:for-each select="cases/case">
      My HTML HERE
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

### UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

I couldn't get this to work.  It was requested that I show my xml.  I'll also post my working xsl:

**XSL File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="suite">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sections"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sections">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <B><xsl:value-of select="name" /></B><BR/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cases/case"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="case">
        <xsl:value-of select="title" /><BR/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<suite>
   <sections>
      <section>
         <name>Section One</name>
         <cases>
            <case>
               <title>XXXX</title>
            </case>
            <case>
               <title>YYYY</title>
            </case>
         </cases>
         <sections>
            <section>
               <name>Section Two</name>
               <cases>
                  <case>
                     <title>ZZZZ</title>
                  </case>
               </cases>
            </section>
         </sections>
      </section>
   </sections>
</suite>
```

My result is only showing:

```
Section One
XXXX
YYYY
```

I would like it to show:

```
Section One
XXXX
YYYY
Section Two
ZZZZ
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what template rules are for. You really shouldn't be using xsl:for-each on recursive narrative structures like this. Your code should look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="suite">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sections">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<template match="section">
  <div class="section">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cases/case"/>
  </div> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="case">
  My HTML HERE
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is still just showing the content from my XML that falls under "suite/sections/section" and not what falls under "suite/sections/section/sections/section".  Any thoughts?

Comment: To debug it I would need to see the full XML source and the full stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks in advance if you can help.  I've posted updates with the xml to the original post.

Comment: In response to your additional information: Your `section` element has a child called `sections` but the template rule for `section` is not processing that child; it is only selecting the `cases/case` branch.

Comment: Right.  Do you know how I can alter the xsl to also process those that are nested that deep?  Thanks!

Comment: You're starting to ask for a training course rather than for answers to specific technical questions. I think you need to do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.  So apparently the templates can actually loop back on each other, should the need arise.  I just included the "sections" inside the "section" template, so it will go back and apply the template appropriately should it find "sections" inside a "section".

So that template what changed with one added line:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <B><xsl:value-of select="name" /></B><BR/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cases/case"/>
    <xsl:comment>ADDED LINE BELOW</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sections"/>
</xsl:template>
```